# Why is my textbox not displaying data from AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In my application, I can verify that the correct info is being selected by using a console.log, but trying to display this info in a form textbox isn't working.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is me view's HTML.

```html
<table class="table table-stripped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="organization in organizations | filter:search" data-ng-click="navToEdit($index)">
            <td>{{organization.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{organization.Title}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is what clicking an item in that list takes you to.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtTitle">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" type="text" id="txtTitle" class="form-control" data-ng-model="organization.Title" />
</div>
```

Here is my controller.

```js
app.controller("organizationsCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", "$routeParams", "spService",    
    function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, spService) {    
        var listTitle = "Organizations";    
    
        $scope.editing = false;    
    
        //example populating Organizations    
        spService.getRecords(listTitle, "?$select=ID,Title").then(function (result) {    
            $scope.organizations = result;    
        });    
    
        $scope.navToAdd = function() {    
            $location.path("/organizations/add");    
        }    
    
        $scope.navToEdit = function(index) {    
            $scope.organization = $scope.organizations[index];    
            $location.path("/organizations/" + index);    
            console.log($scope.organization.Title);   
        }    
    }    
]);
```

$scope.navToEdit does output the correct organization, but the textbox of txtTitle doesn't show anything.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

As i see , the problem here is you are redirecting to another page here,

**`$location.path("/organizations/" + index);`**

which will clear the existing scope within the controller, if you want to transfer the data from one page to another use service or localStorage.

Comment: So if I use a service to store my data I can just recall if between page loads?

Comment: Yeah you can do that

Comment: I was just reading about $rootScope.  How does that work or would it help at all?